# Check current user in batch

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I want to check in a batch script if the current user logged in is a certain user in the domain.
what i had in mind was:

```
if %username% == "Some_User_Name" (
...
)
```

When I do this its just skip the part in the: ().
I know the user name is correct.

can anyone tell me what is wrong and how to right it?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2 Solutions:

`if %username% == (Value of %Some_User_Name%)`

or

```
if "%username%"=="%Some_User_Name%" goto IfStatement

:IfStatement
(Your code here)
```

**CASE SENSITIVE!**

Comment: you can make it case insensitive with `if /i ...`

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

```
C:\> if %USERNAME% == abelenky echo Current User Found
Current User Found
```

***Notes:***
It is case-sensitive on the string compared against (`abelenky`).
Putting in `AbElEnKy` does not work.

However, it is not case-sensitive for the environment variable: `%UsErNaMe%` worked just fine.

Comment: you can make it case insensitive with `if /i ...`